# Latex multiline multicol and multirow page-wide table

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I have some trouble while creating complicated (for me) table.

To be:

[image: table example]

I wrote that code:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Short text} & \multicolumn{4}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+4\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Some long multi column text that can be multi line} & \multirow{2}{*}{Some long one column text that can be multi line}  & \multirow{2}{*}{Some long one column text that can be multi line} &  \multirow{2}{*}{Some long one column text that can be multi line}\\
\hline
& long_word & long_word & long_word & long_word &  &  &  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

But words in second line are not hyphenated. And multirow doesn't work.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are the final three columns supposed to have the same width? Are the first five columns supposed to have equal widths? Should the combined width of columns 2 thru 5 equal the width of column 6? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico, thank for reply!
Proportionally columns should be so: 1-1-1-1-1-3-2-2

Answer (score 6):

The table width calculations for your table are somewhat more involved than usual, since you're specifying ratios for the *total* column widths rather than for the *usable* column widths. LaTeX needs to be given information about the usable column widths. One has to subtract any whitespace padding and the widths of vertical rules from the total column widths in order to obtain the usable columns widths.

Let's label the *usable* column widths `\xlen`, `\ylen`, and `\zlen`, respectively, and the *total* column widths `\xtotlen`, `\ytotlen`, and `\ztotlen`, respectively. The total column widths must satisfy

```
5\xtotlen+\ytotlen+2\ztotlen=\textwidth
\ytotlen=3\xtotlen
\ztotlen=2\totxlen
```

(Aside: Observe that `\textwidth=12\xtotlen`.)

Next, recall that

```
\xtotlen=\xlen+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth
\ytotlen=\ylen+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth
\ztotlen=\zlen+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth
```

After some rearranging, we may express the *usable* column widths as follows:

```
\xlen = (\textwidth-24\tabcolsep-12\arrayrulewidth)/12
\ylen = 3\xlen+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth
\zlen = 2\xlen+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth
```

Eagle-eyed readers may have noticed that these calculations have failed to incorporate the width of the very first vertical rule, located to the left of the first column; its width is equal to `\arrayrulewidth`. To make the width calculations truly correct, then, one must change `\xlen = (\textwidth-24\tabcolsep-12\arrayrulewidth)/12` to `\xlen = (\textwidth-24\tabcolsep-13\arrayrulewidth)/12`. (Given that the default value of `\tabcolsep` is `0.4pt`, I doubt anyone would ever notice the difference.)

---

OK, enough talk! Let's see how this all works out.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{array}    % for \newcolumntype macro
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

%% Compute the three column widths:
\newlength\xlen
\setlength\xlen{\dimexpr\textwidth-24\tabcolsep-13\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\setlength\xlen{\dimexpr0.08333333\xlen\relax} % 1/12 \approx 0.08333333
\newlength\ylen
\setlength\ylen{\dimexpr3\xlen+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\newlength\zlen
\setlength\zlen{\dimexpr2\xlen+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth\relax}

\newcommand\longword{long\_\discretionary{}{}{}word}

\begin{document}
\noindent % <-- this is important
\begin{tabular}{ | *{5}{P{\xlen}|} P{\ylen}| *{2}{P{\zlen}|} }
\hline
  \multirow{4}{=}{Short text}
& \multicolumn{4}{>{\RaggedRight}P{\dimexpr4\xlen+6\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth}|}{%
     Some long multi-column text which can be multi-line} 
& \multirow{4}{=}{Some long one-column text which can be multi-line}
& \multirow{4}{=}{Some long one-column text which can be multi-line}
& \multirow{4}{=}{Some long one-column text which can be multi-line} \\
\cline{2-5} % not "\hline"
& \longword & \longword & \longword & \longword &  &  &  \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's good! But "longword"s are different in columns, and how to merge rows in columns 1, 6, 7, 8?

Comment: @AlekseiLiubimov - I've updated the answer to throw in a few `\multirow` directives.

Answer (score 4):

For fixed width column, in a `\multirow`,you should use the `{=}`width argument, not `{*}`. Furthermore, in case of multilined cells, the first argument, should be the total number of encompassed lines, not the number of rows. Furthermore again, for fine-tuning of the vertical position of the multirow contents, you can use a non-integer number of lines. Finally, as  tabularx seems to have problems with fixed width column types in the argument of `\multicolumn}`, I used a `multicolumn{4}{c}{\makecell{...\\...}}`, where line breaks are done by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\centering\small
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{>{\hsize=0.66\hsize}X|}>{\hsize=2\hsize}X|*{2}{>{\hsize=1.35\hsize}X|}}
\hline
 \multirow{3}{=}{Short text} &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\makecell{Some long multi column text\\ that can be multi line}} 
& \multirow{3}{=}{Some long one column text that can be multi line} & \multirow{2}{=}{Some long one column text that can be multi line} & \multirow{2}{=}{Some long one column text that can be multi line}\\
\cline{2-5}
& long\_ word & long\_ word & long\_ word & long\_ word & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to write `*{2}{>{\hsize=uuu\hsize}X|}` instead of `*{5}{>{\hsize=1.675\hsize}X|}` (where the factor `uuu` needs to be recomputed as well)?

Comment: @Mico: Yes. The result of my calculations to obtain the prescribed column widths ratios were that the first  5 columns were 2/3 \hsize, the sixthcolumn,  2 \hize and the last two, 4/3 \hsize. I rounded these results to decimal values so that the total remained equal to 8.

Comment: What's the purpose of specifying 5 rather than just 2 columns on the right side?

Comment: Oh! Verifying, it was a typo, which I didn't detect from the resulting table because all columns were not used. I'll fix that in a moment. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: I think you also need to change `>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize-6\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}X` to `>{\hsize=\dimexpr2.6667\hsize+6\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth\relax}X`. Why 2.667 rather than 4? Because the usable width of the underlying columns isn't `\hsize` but "only" `0.667\hsize`.

Comment: @Mico: I thought the value of `\hsize` was the value in the current, but I see it worked only because of my typo set of  `X` columns. Actually, using `\multicolumn` with `X` columns is a mess, and I found simpler to use a `\multicolumn{4}{c}{\makecell{…}`, which seems to work nicely. Of course, line breaks inside have to be done by hand, but I don't  think it's such a big problem in this context.

Answer (score 0):

just out of curiosity since the author said

```
  Proportionally columns should be so: 1-1-1-1-1-3-2-2
```

dividing the textwidth into 12 columns --

the first 5 columns  are 0.08 times textwidth --

the next is 3 times 0.08 --

and the last two are 2 times 0.08

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
    {
        |*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.08\hsize}X|}
        *{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.24\hsize}X|}
        *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.16\hsize}X|}
    }
            \hline%
           G  & G & G & G & G & G & G & G \\
            \hline%
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding `X` type columns of different widths using `\hsize=...`, the `tabularx` manual states: "Make sure that the sum of the widths of all the `X` columns is unchanged.  In your code, the widths add up to a total of `0.96` while they should add up to 8, since your code contains 8 `X` type columns. Your approach dividing teh `\textwidth`by 12 would be more suitable if `p` type columns and a regular `tabular` were involved. (With `p` type columns you would however, make sure you also take into account the \tabcolsep as well as teh width of the vertical lines, just as Mico did in their answer.